# iOS: error submitting app to app store

Tags: ios, itunes, release

I'm trying to submit my app to the app store but this weird error is showing in each one of my team's member (although we have already submitted the same app with those provisions):

[image]

[image]

[image]

We're under tight schedule to release the app - so help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using an "App Store" provisioning profile under "Code Signing" -> "Provisioning Profile" -> "Release". I'm seeing "Automatic" in your screenshot which mean it could be using an Ad Hoc or Development provisioning profile. I recommend using separate build targets to keep all these settings separated.

Comment: yeah i've ended creating a new provisioning profile and refreshed everything

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but u can try this. 
Delete all Provisioning Profile from you system.And the reinstalled only the required Provisioning Profile for this app.